# How to Add Controls to a Form on an Excel Sheet (Not to a VBA Form)

Tags: excel, vba, forms, controls, multipage

This seems like it should be easy but I can't seem to figure out how to do it...

In Excel, it is possible to add a Form directly to a Sheet. For example, under Developer > Insert > Active X Controls > More Controls > Microsoft Forms 2.0 MultiPage. How does one now add a control (say a push button) that is associated with one of the tabs within the MultiPage? So that, say, PushButton1 is on Tab1 and PushButton2 is on Tab2 when you exit Design Mode and actually select the tabs?

In VBA it is trivial. Create a User Form, add a MultiPage to it, and then just plop the push buttons onto the desired tabs. How do you do this with a form that's on an Excel sheet?

Thank you in advance!

[image: MultiPage on a Excel Sheet with a Push Button in Design Mode]

[image: Same MultiPage with DesignMode Turned Off]

[image: MultiPage with Buttons in VBA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In design mode:

1. Right Click on MultiPage -> MultiPage-Object -> Edit
2. Right Click again -> toolbox

Comment: Oh, FFS! THANK YOU!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know the answer to a related question, would you?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183538/detect-button-press-event-on-an-excel-sheet-multipage-form-not-a-vba-multipage