# Detect Button Press Event on an Excel Sheet MultiPage Form (NOT a VBA MultiPage)

Tags: vba, excel, button, multipage

I am struggling to figure out how to detect a button press event on a MultiPage form that resides directly on an Excel sheet. In other words, the form is not generated using VBA, it is built directly on the sheet.

I expect the syntax to be something like:

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Frame1_CommandButton1_Click()
    Do Stuff
End Sub
```

However, that doesn't work because I think I also need to specify the page in the MultiPage. For example, a text box on the same form can be accessed via:

```
MultiPage1.Pages(0).Frame1.TextBox1.Text = "Some Text"
```

Unfortunately,

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Pages(0)_Frame1_CommandButton1_Click()
```

gives a Compile error: Expected: identifier with the zero inside (0) selected.

So, how do I convert

```
MultiPage1.Pages(0).Frame1.CommandButton1
```

to a Sub name that will detect the button press event?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you insert the MultiPage control on a worksheet? I didn't think that was an option. You could instead try referencng the "page object": see ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson8.htm

Comment: Under Insert Active-X Controls there is an option for More Controls (last button) that brings up a whole bunch of things that can be inserted. Sorry, not in front of a PC right now to grab a screenshot.

Comment: @MichaelA Which version of Excel ?

Comment: Excel 2016 on Windows 10.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It's a shame though. You could however "fake" it with a tabstrip and a grey rectangular form beneath it, making your controls visible on whatever tab you click on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mikerickson and Jaafar Tribak on MrExcel.com figured it out:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1054446-detect-button-press-event-excel-sheet-multipage-form-not-vba-userform-multipage-2.html

Big thanks to both of them!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think you may have stumbled onto a bug.

There is a Microsoft Forms 2.0 Control under *More Controls*, but I'm pretty sure it's only intended only for use on UserForms.

I tried adding it to a worksheet and got an error.  However, once I added one to a UserForm and went back to the worksheet, I was able to add it...  but things got "glitchy" for moment, and when I opened the Properties dialog for the bod, the font was poorly rendered.

All the documentation that I looked at (like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/how-to-access-a-page-in-a-multipage-control), [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440949(v=office.12).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/how-to-add-a-control-to-a-multipage-control)) only have examples of it being used on a UserForm, or in Outlook.

There are many types of ActiveX controls, and not all of them can be used anywhere.  As a rule of thumb in Excel, it's best to stick to the controls that are built-in.

Also, from another forum:

> **Q**: It seems that I could not find and add Multipage control into worksheet.
>   How to add a Multipage control to Excel worksheet?
>
> **A**: Unless you put it on a UserForm first, you can't display it on a Worksheet. The UserForm provides the user interface to VBA. The MultiPagecontrol is designed to work with this user interface, and not the Excel Worksheet. Is there a problem using the UserForm to display the MutliPage control?  <sub>Source: [Leith Ross](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/553100-can-i-put-multipage-control-on-workseet.html#post1625778)</sub>

[image: img]

This evidence combined tells me, *even if you can get it to work,* **you shouldn't**.  There's no predicting how it will behave.

---

In case you decide to use a MultiPage on a UserForm, note that in your example above, `MultiPage1` is the name of the **control**; that's not referring to "page 1".  The control *as a whole* has a `Click` event which is not specific to a page:

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Click(ByVal Index As Long)
```

---

For the sake of completeness, I'll paste in a complete code sample but once again: this is **not recommended** for a worksheet-based control.

### How to: Access a Page in a MultiPage Control

The following example accesses an individual page of a *MultiPage* in several ways:

- Using the Pages collection with a numeric index.
- Using the name of the individual page in the MultiPage.
- Using the SelectedItem property.

To use this example, copy this sample code to the *Script Editor* of a **form**. Make sure that the **form** contains a **MultiPage** named `MultiPage1` and a **CommandButton** named `CommandButton1`.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim PageName
    Set MultiPage1 = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages("P.2").MultiPage1

    For i = 0 To MultiPage1.Count - 1
        'Use index (numeric or string)
        MsgBox "MultiPage1.Pages(i).Caption = " & MultiPage1.Pages(i).Caption
        MsgBox "MultiPage1.Pages.Item(i).Caption = " & _
            MultiPage1.Pages.Item(i).Caption

        'Use Page object without referring to Pages collection
        If i = 0 Then
            MsgBox "MultiPage1.Page1.Caption = " & MultiPage1.Page1.Caption
        ElseIf i = 1 Then
            MsgBox "MultiPage1.Page2.Caption = " & MultiPage1.Page2.Caption
        End If

        'Use SelectedItem Property
        MultiPage1.Value = i
        MsgBox "MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Caption = " & _
            MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Caption
    Next
End Sub
```

([**Source**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/how-to-access-a-page-in-a-multipage-control))

---

Now I'm going to delete that buggy worksheet and ***reboot***; I'd suggest you do the same!

Comment: Thank you for trying. I actually have zero problems with my MultiPage directly on a sheet other than not being able to capture a button press. The MultiPage has Text Boxes that I can set with Active X buttons placed directly on the sheet. It has a List Box that is populated on Workbook open. Switching Tabs on the MultiPage works fine and generates a Click event I can capture. In other words, no problems other than not being able to capture the button press for a button in the MP. Just can't figure out the right syntax for the Sub name... 

Comment: Correction: you have zero problems *so far*.

Comment: Also, the button should be the easiest to add code to.  Different behaviours on your machijnenand mine... that was i meant by "upredictable".... its a bad idea, you'll see